# Swift closure returning empty values

Tags: swift, closures

I was reading this article about high order functions

https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/simple-higher-order-functions-in-swift-3-0-map-filter-reduce-and-flatmap-984fa00b2532

then I started playing around with them and found this:

```
let someArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let newArray  = someArray.map {
    print($0)
    $0 * 2
}
print(a)
```

this would return empty values in `newArray`

[image]

while removing the `print` function or specifically setting the function's return type would work:

```
let a  = someArray.map { number -> Int in
    print(number)
    return number * 2
}
print(a)
```

[image]

Any explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because if you use **Shorthand Argument Names** in closure **you have to return from very first line** i.e. inline return.
In your first closure you'r first line is `print()` which returns nothing.
If you do like this:

```
let newArray  = someArray.map {
  $0 * 2
}
```

Or simply this:

```
let newArray  = someArray.map { $0 * 2 }
```

you will get the result.

Read more about this [here in developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

---

**Update**
As shown by @hamish, multiple calculations can be done with shorthand arguments but then we need to explicitly mention data type of result and also `return` statement as:

```
let newArray: [Int] = someArray.map {
  print($0)
  return $0 * 2
}
```

Comment: yes, i do know how to use short hand arguments, it's just that i don't understand why simply printing the iterated values would have an impact on them

Comment: it's not about printing or doing anything else, it's about you must have to have only A calculation line inside closure

Comment: so basically I can't do more than one line calculation?

Comment: YES, if you'r using **shorthand arguments** like `$0`, `$1`

Comment: This has nothing to do with shorthand closure arguments – you can use them in multi-statement closures, e.g `let newArray: [Int]  = someArray.map { print($0); return $0 * 2 }`

Comment: yes, this too works fine; again, if we don't mention result type (`let newArr: [Int]`) with shorthand arguments then we've to use single line closures

Comment: @Hamish nice!! Then I can still use shorthand arguments, I'll just have to specify the return line

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use `return` in a closure that should return something, then the result of the first statement is returned. In this case void (aka the empty tuple: `()` ) which is returned by the `print` function.

Calling functions like `print` in a map closure is bad practice since it could have side effects and should be avoided.